# How to clean up numbered labels on the bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, aesthetics

I was wondering how I could go about cleaning up the numbers on the graph. Attached is a sample dataframe with the code. The actual database is 1300 entries. Ill be cleaning up the NAs and misc entries. But I would like to keep the total numbers and the percentages for the categories in a way that's legible.

Thank you!

```
UnnestQ3 <- data.frame(Q3 = c ("mail", "email", "mail", "mail", 
                            "Demonstration", "Videos (Ex: Youtube)",
                            "Podcast", "Podcast", "mail"), Gender = c ("male", "male", "female", "male", "female", "NA", "NA", "Other", "Male")

ggplot(UnnestQ3, aes(x = Q3, fill = D1)) +
      geom_bar(width = 0.75) +
      theme_minimal(base_size = 10) +
       geom_text(aes(label = paste0(..count..,"(",round(..count..*100/nrow(UnnestQ3)), "%)")), stat = "count", vjust = 0, colour = "black") +
      coord_flip() +
      labs(x = "Communication Method") +
      labs(y = "Total Number of Responses (N)") +
      scale_fill_viridis_d()
```

[image: Bar graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `position_stack` in your text layer. I would also make the text color conditional on `Gender` so that it is legible against dark background fills:

```r
ggplot(UnnestQ3, aes(x = Q3, fill = Gender)) +
 geom_bar(width = 0.75) +
 theme_minimal(base_size = 10) +
 geom_text(aes(label = paste0(..count..," (", 
                              round(..count..*100/nrow(UnnestQ3)), "%)"),
               color = Gender), 
           stat = "count", vjust = 0,  
           position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
   scale_color_manual(values = c("white", "white", "white", "black", "black"),
                      guide = "none") +
   coord_flip() +
   labs(x = "Communication Method") +
   labs(y = "Total Number of Responses (N)") +
   scale_fill_viridis_d()
```

[image]